# How to write or print multiple variable outputs with headers, line by line per tick to command center in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How does one write or print multiple variable outputs with headers, line by line per tick to command center in netlogo? the idea is to print out ticking results of more than one variable (reported by procedures) so that it appears in they appear as follows in the command center output window:

```
length weight height area 
24.2   23.1   22.0   25.1 
18.7   19.2   10.4   22.0
```

and so on, updating per tick in columnar form.

I eventually want to be able to use the export-output command to transport the output to a csv file at the end of the simulation run. I know there are other ways of doing this but I want it this way specifically for a reason.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're imagining?

Comment: @Bryan Head the idea is to print out ticking results of more than one variable (reported by procedures) so that it appears in they appear as follows in the command center output window: `length weight height area` and in the line beneath that, say, `24.2 23.1 22.0 25.1` and in the following line `18.7 19.2 10.4 22.0` and so on, updating per tick in columnar form. I eventually want to be able to use the `export-output` command to transport the output to a csv file at the end of the simulation run. I know there are other ways of doing this but I want it this way specifically for a reason.

Comment: You can edit your question to improve it; you don't have to pile everything into a comment.

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks, I will do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `type` and `print` commands. Your heading would need to be printed during initialisation and the variable values would need to be printed each tick. Assuming your procedures are named cal-length etc, code would look something like this. Note that there is no spacing control or other formatting.

```
to setup
  ...
  print "length   weight   height   area"
  ...
end

to go
  ...
  dump-to-screen
  ...
end

to dump-to-screen
  type calc-length type "   " type calc-weight type "   "
  type calc-height type "   " print calc-area
end
```